# adding a function in href using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I've just added this piece of code in my JSP

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $('a').click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert ('hello');
        return false; } );
</script>
```

but nothing happens when I click to a

Comment: — Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: can You try with jQuery instead of $ , also wrap your code in dom ready

Comment: like some answer told you, you should execute this when the page is ready, because you need to be sure that yours link are loaded in the DOM. If not, `$('a')` will return nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are invoking the click event on "a" without getting the DOM ready, so just put your script in document.ready as, it will work

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(document).ready(function()
        $('a').click( function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert ('hello');
            return false; 
        });
    )};
</script>
```

Comment: Even if it works, I am tempted to downvote you since you didn't explain your answer. This is not helpful in this state ;) please explain why we should do this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(document).ready(function)` Then only listen the js at the time of you click

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert ('hello');
        return false; } )
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a >click</a>
```